# Terraform aws create and delete resource in same template

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, endpoint

i tried to create a aws_vpc_endpoint with type "Interface".
But i have to set the IP to the last one in this subnet.
Because VPC_Endpoint doesn't provide a option to set the IP i tried to first create a aws_network_interface in the same subnet which reserves all IPs in the subnet except the last one. (because i am using /28 subnets it is possible with just one interface)

```
resource "aws_network_interface" "placeholder" {
  subnet_id   = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
  description = "test"

  private_ips = [
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 4)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 5)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 6)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 7)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 8)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 9)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 10)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 11)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 12)}",
    "${cidrhost("${var.pp-cidr}", 13)}",
  ]
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "ec2" {
  vpc_id              = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.eu-central-1.ec2"
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  security_group_ids  = ["${aws_security_group.sg-endpoint1.id}"]
  private_dns_enabled = true
  depends_on          = ["aws_network_interface.placeholder"]
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_subnet_association" "sn_ec2" {
  vpc_endpoint_id = "${aws_vpc_endpoint.ec2.id}"
  subnet_id       = "${aws_subnet.subnet.id}"
}
```

My problem is now that i have to delete the interface after creation of the endpoint but i cannot find an option which enables me to

Any ideas

Comment: Why does it need to be in the last IP address of the subnet?

Comment: You can set `count=0` in the resource and ensure that it is the last resource created (or in this case deleted) using depends_on attribute.